# Failed to send POST request with "curl" from command line

Tags: forms, post, curl

I have a `Jersey` service with a method to handle form submission.

```
void handle(@FormParam("name") String name) {...}
```

When I submit a form (see below) in a browser the service works Ok.

```
<form action="rest/myService" method="POST">
    <input name="name"/>
</form>
```

Now I am trying to send the form submission `POST` request with `curl` from the command line (see below) but the "FormParameter" `name` in the service is `null` while I expect it to be set to `myName`.

```
curl -d "name=myName" http://localhost:8080/myApp/rest/myService
```

I guess the `curl` command line is wrong. Is it correct? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert, but try to replace -d with -F

good luck

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the difference b/w -d and -F ?

Comment: @Michael `man curl` will give you the detailed explanation. I just can't post the help in the a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/myApp/rest/myService -d "name=myName"
```

or

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/myApp/rest/myService --data-urlencode "name=myName"
```

would produce a POST